# How do I clear my local working directory in Git?

Tags: git

How can I clear my working directory in Git?

Comment: User interactive approach: git clean -i -fd

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been **flagged duplicate**. That [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree) clearly deals with removing only `untracked` files from `working directory` and not `modified` files

Comment: @y2k-shubham Sure, but *this* question is vague and doesn't explicitly refer to modified files.

Answer (score 1179, accepted):

To reset a specific file to the last-committed state (to discard uncommitted changes in a specific file):

```
git checkout thefiletoreset.txt
```

This is mentioned in the `git status` output:

```
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

To reset the entire repository to the last committed state:

```
git reset --hard
```

To remove untracked files, I usually just delete all files in the working copy (but **not** the `.git/` folder!), then do `git reset --hard` which leaves it with only committed files.

A better way is to use `git clean` (**warning**: using the `-x` flag as below will cause Git to delete ignored files):

```
git clean -d -x -f
```

will remove untracked files, including directories (`-d`) and files ignored by git (`-x`). Replace the `-f` argument with `-n` to perform a dry-run or `-i` for interactive mode, and it will tell you what will be removed.

Relevant links:

- [git-reset man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)
- [git-clean man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html)
- [git ready "cleaning up untracked files"](http://www.gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/16/cleaning-up-untracked-files.html) (as Marko posted)
- Stack Overflow question *["How to remove local (untracked) files from the current Git working tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree)*)

Comment: Note that by default, 'git clean -d' is insufficient.  You need to also add the -f (force) flag.  Also, if you want to additionally delete the files that are ignored by .gitignore, then you need to add the -x option.  Here's what it all looks like:   git clean -xdf

Comment: However be sure to NOTE that command will also blow away your local sqlite database -- not undo recent changes, but actually delete it. Sp the "-x" option might NOT ne a good idea depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am 100% sure I run git clean -d -f ( without -x ) and it also deleted ignored files.

Comment: Please note: the suggestion to delete all the files except the `.git/` folder and then restore by running `git reset --hard` will probably take a long time if your repo has been around for any time at all. Please don't do this. Use `git clean`.

Comment: One thing I found in trying to use this command, is knowing if that was in fact the problem. Turns out one of my colleagues had the dropdown in 'Working Copy' at the top of the page set to 'All Files' when it should be 'Pending'. This gave the appearance that a load of files were being changed, when in fact, it was just showing all the files in the project, as it should do. So the fix for this issue was just to select 'Pending Files' from the dropdown in 'Working Copy' screen. Let me know if this helps anyone.

Comment: Note also that `git clean -d -x -f` will blow away symlinks to outside directories.

Comment: The `git clean -fdx` option is very useful. It helped me delete some untracked files that were hidden and that I did not know that were affecting my compilation.

Comment: **Warning** don't forget `-n` for a dry-run !

Comment: Quick addition: you could reset the entire subdirectory using wildcards like this. Notice the quotes around the pattern.
```git checkout master 'subdir/*' ```

Comment: `git restore <deleted files>` was required in my case, after the clean -dxf .

Answer (score 164):

Use:

```
git clean -df
```

It's not well advertised, but `git clean` is really handy. *Git Ready* has a [nice introduction to `git clean`](http://www.gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/16/cleaning-up-untracked-files.html).

Comment: I suggest to not use the `-x` parameter as it will remove all gitignored content. Say you have a folder named '`gitignored`' added to `.gitignore`, and you store there your files that have to be secure, you're also deleting them using `-x` parameter

Comment: Oops. `git clean -xdf` also removed `.gitignore`, and I did not notice before the next commit. I won't ignore `.gitignore` anymore. :)

Comment: @Grastveit `git clean -xdf` will remove `.gitignore` if and only if it has not been added to, thus working as intended.

Comment: let's highlight this:       -        

Comment: @mef I use `git clean -xdf` all the time instead of make clean, ant clean, mvn clean or whatever else. There's no general rule, and everyone is free to use `-x` or not.

Comment: @Marko sure, everyone is free to use `-x` or not. But some people may read this github answer, copy-paste the command, and without realizing it loose all their gitignored files they wanted to keep. Then come back here and only notice @Highmastdon's comment, about the consequence of using `-x`.

Answer (score 51):

All the answers so far retain local commits.  If you're **really** serious, you can discard all local commits and all local edits by doing:

```
git reset --hard origin/branchname
```

For example:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This makes your local repository **exactly match** the state of the origin (other than untracked files).

If you accidentally did this after just reading the command, and not what it does :), use git reflog to find your old commits.

Comment: Is branch name really required? For me `git reset --hard` simply works for current working branch without branch name.

Comment: Without the branch, it does not clear local commits.

Comment: ohh. ok. My observation was only regarding the local modified and newly added untracked files. So if I got you correctly, if any file is staged or has already been committed in local branch (not pushed as yet) will not get cleaned if I do not use the branch  name explicitly. Correct?

Comment: Super. I verified your observation.  You were correct buddy. `git reset --hard` doesn't clear local commits until you specify the branch name explicitly. +1.

Comment: Git really has to be the most complex and unfriendly source control system. I tried everything to fix up my local copy, and only this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You could create a commit which contains an empty working copy.

This is a generally safe, non-destructive approach because it does not involve the use of any brute-force reset mechanisms.  First you hide all managed content with `git checkout empty`, then you are free to manually review and remove whatever unmanaged content remains.

```
## create a stand-alone, tagged, empty commit
true | git mktree | xargs git commit-tree | xargs git tag empty

## clear the working copy
git checkout empty
```

Your working copy should now be clear of any managed content.  All that remains are unmanaged files and the `.git` folder itself.

To re-populate your working copy...

```
git checkout master ## or whatever branch you will be using
```

---

If you're a forward thinking individual, you might start your repository off on the right foot by basing everything on an initial empty commit...

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty --allow-empty-message -m ""
git tag empty
...
```

---

There are various uses for a tagged empty worktree.  My favorite at the moment is to depopulate the root under a set of `git worktree` subfolders.

Comment: This can also be a nice way to save some disk-space in a pinch.

Comment: A much faster way to create the empty checkout: `true | git mktree | xargs git commit-tree | xargs git tag empty`

Comment: Note: There seems to be some value in using an empty commit as the base for projects.  This makes it easier to perform full-project rebase operations in case your initial commit needs to be fixed -- and may simplify things when [pushing an existing git repository to svn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn).

Comment: Like most other workflows, this gets messy if you are using Git submodules.

Comment: 'git init && git commit --allow-empty "EMPTY COMMIT && git tag empty' would do the job of the first block too.

Comment: You may have better luck if you do a `make clean` or equivalent before checking out `empty`. :)

Answer (score 9):

To switch to another branch, discarding all uncommitted changes (e.g. resulting from Git's strange handling of line endings):

```
git checkout -f <branchname>
```

I had a working copy with hundreds of changed files (but empty `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol`) which I couldn't get rid off with any of the commands I read here, and `git checkout <branchname>` won't work, either - unless given the `-f` (or `--force`) option.

Answer (score 2):

To reset a specific file as git status suggests:

```
git checkout <filename>
```

To reset a folder

```
git checkout <foldername>/*
```