# cvs update equivalent in git no remote repository

Tags: git

I have `git status` reporting numerous files deleted from my sandbox:

```
#   deleted:    prj1/.classpath
#   deleted:    prj1/.project
#   deleted:    prj1/default.properties
#   deleted:    prj2/.classpath
#   deleted:    prj2/default.properties
#   deleted:    prj3/.classpath
#   deleted:    prj3/default.properties
#   deleted:    prj4/.classpath
#   deleted:    prj4/default.properties
#   deleted:    prj5/.classpath
#   deleted:    prj5/default.properties
#   deleted:    prj6/.classpath
#   deleted:    prj6/default.properties
#   deleted:    prj7/.classpath
#   deleted:    prj7/default.properties
```

Now I want to check them out from the **local** repository (.git, I don't have a remote repository).

In CVS I used to just do `cvs update` and it would restore all missing files, in the entire hierarchy.

How do I do the same in Git?

I know about `git pull origin master` but that only works with a remote repository.

I also know about `git checkout -- file` but I don't want to type all the file names and their paths. I am looking for something as convenient as `cvs update`.

How do I do that in git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This will revert everything to the last committed state, including files you have deleted.

Comment: Yes, I just found [it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5812972/1124861) after much search. There is a difference, though, as `cvs update` will not step over modified files, unlike `git reset --hard HEAD`. Is there a more precise equivalent? Thanks +1.

Comment: Well if you only want to restore deleted files this may work for you `git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout --`