# How to ignore all modification added in new branch

Tags: git

I recently create a new branch using Git, and after a lot of modification in this branch i want to return in the previous state and remove all this changes with this branch.

for now changes are not staged and i didn't any commit

what is the best way to do this ? thank you

Comment: You want to discard all of the changes you made?

Comment: yes exactly what i want

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git - how to revert uncommitted changes including files and folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807137/git-how-to-revert-uncommitted-changes-including-files-and-folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely remove all uncommitted changes (and don't care about being able to get them back), `git reset --hard` will do the trick.

Comment: what about git checkout -f ?

Comment: `git checkout -f` will remove uncommitted changes to already-tracked files but will ignore any uncommitted new files. Depends on what the OP wants.

Comment: thank you for answer just one question : is "git reset --hard" enough ? because all Changes are not staged yet for commit

Comment: @medBo `git reset --hard` resets *everything* in the working directory, regardless of whether it's staged.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do what you asked, and will depend on how permanent you want it to be.

Usually you would use the [`checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) command to undo unstaged changes.  I'd suggest reading through the documentation for a more complete description of what the command does, but a few helpful commands are

```
git checkout -- .     # undo changes to all files in current directory and 
                      # sub-directories
git checkout -- :/    # if you happen to not be in the root directory, but want
                      # to undo changes in the entire repository instead of just 
                      # the current sub-directory
git checkout -p       # patched undo, allows you to select which changes you want 
                      # to undo and which you don't
```

If you happened to have had changes stages that you wanted to undo, you would use

```
git reset --hard
```

as Amber suggests.  This has the same effect as doing

```
git reset
git checkout -- .
```

If you find yourself in a situation where you find something broken, and you're not sure if it was your code that broke it or if it was already broken when you started, you can use the [stash](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) command.

```
git stash
```

This will save your changes into a temporary area and reverting your working directory to be the last commit.  You can use `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` to bring your uncommitted changes back into the working directory.

You may find [git cheatsheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html#loc=workspace;) helpful.  It helps visualize what each git command acts on.