# Is "git reset --hard" the same as "git reset --hard HEAD"?

Tags: git, github, git-reset

In order to revert changes in a working tree and index, this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5812972/8278160) suggests that one run the following:

```
git reset --hard
```

Would running this be the same as running `git reset --hard HEAD`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `HEAD` is implied if not specified, so it's the same thing.

*[Source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset-Undoamergeorpull)* [bullet item #2]