# Get Error while building libav on windows using minGW and MSYS

Tags: permissions, makefile, mingw, msys, libav

I have a trouble with [libav.](http://libav.org)
I used MinGW and MSYS to build libav on windows. However, When I use "make", after some file(.o file) were build i get error,
It is

```
$ make 
AR    libavcodec/libavcodec.a C:\msys\mingw\bin\ar.exe: libavcodec/: Permission denied 
make: *** [libavcodec/libavcodec.a] Error 1
```

After that, I view the permission of libavcodec folder, I have all permission. :|
Please help me solve this trouble or give me a full instruction to build libav on windows (I use win7 x64 and have msys, mingw)
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I had the same error when trying to make ffmpeg. Initially I was getting a missing separator error (in one of the makefiles) when I used configure. I found [a page](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/1209) that suggested checking that git was using unix line endings rather than windows (CR LF). So I used

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

to set git to use unix line endings and then thought I'd updated my source (being new to git, it turned out I hadn't). I still got the missing separator error, so I added a tab to the start of the line and configure completed. I then used make and would get the same error you're getting. I saw in some of the other makefiles that they still had windows line endings, so I deleted the entire directory apart from the .git folder as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673407/how-do-i-clear-my-local-working-directory-in-git), and then used

```
git reset --hard
```

to get the files again. After this configure and make worked without error, so my guess would be that you're using windows line endings or there's something wrong with the makefiles.

Comment: +1 That did it for me. I worship the keyboard you typed this answer on.