# How to avoid files in .gitignore keep showing in another branch?

Tags: git

I have two branches which contain their own version of `node_modules`, but in different folders.

**Branch 1:**

```
--client/
--server/
--node_modules/
...
```

**Branch 2:**

```
--server/
-----/node_modules/
...
```

So, when I switched from `Branch 2 -> Branch 1`, it contained the following folders:

```
--client/
--server/
-----/node_modules/
--node_modules/
...
```

This made an error because Node will use the nested version instead of the outer one. So, my question is how to disappear files specified in `.gitignore`, for example `node_modules` in this case, when checking out another branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try (dry-run test)

```
git clean -d -x -n
```

To see, just after a git checkout, if that would remove the right files.
See "[How do I clear my local working directory in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/675797/6309)"

The other approach would be a `git reset --hard` right after the `git checkout`.

---

If you cannot easily remove the (`.gitignore`'d) `node_modules` folder, then a third approach would be to work in tow different folders, one for each branch.
See "[Multiple working directories with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)": since Git 2.5+, you can clone once, and checkout different branches in different folders.
Switching branches becomes as easy as a `cd ../otherbranch`.

Comment: Does this mean the `node_modules` will be deleted? If so, could we only make it disappear for a while and get it back whenever we switch back? Because I sometimes need to switch to another branch to do just simple thing, and then, switch back. I don't want to do `npm install` or `git pull` every time I switch.

Comment: @LVarayut then it is best to keep `node_modules` generated content (by npm install) *outside* the repo (not versioned)

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly but `node_modules` is already ignored by using `.gitignore`. Did you mean to keep it outside the current working directory? If so, I'm not quite sure if it's a good idea.

Comment: @LVarayut Then I have edited my answer to propose an alternative.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.