# Xcode not retrieves all files when switching branch with git

Tags: xcode, git, terminal, xcode8

I am working with XCode on an IOS app. I created a branch and commit it and push to GitLab after my modifications done. (with Mac terminal in command lines)

I switched branch, there was files in red added from my previous branch that I removed from the project.

But when I came back to my previous branch files in Xcode didn't change and my modification were gone although I can see the added files in the location of my project in finder.

Is someone can help me ?

Comment: Do. `git clean -fdx`. [Here are more details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/675797/1457385).

Comment: I tried but did not help, even when I downloaded from gitlab the project of my commit I have the same issue :(