# why does git checkout . or invalidate cache not get rid of files in my android project

Tags: git, android-studio

I've tried to revert to a desired file state for an android project by using `git checkout .` as well as through invalidating the cache in IntelliJ, to no avail.

How do I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A git reset --hard should have been enough, but you might have untracked files.

For that, see "[How do I clear my local working directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/675797/6309)"

```
git clean -d -x -f
```

In both cases, make sure you don't have any work in progress (or save it) *before typing any of those commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio and your project is connected through VCS it's simple to revert your file by doing this:

1. Go to `VCS => Local History => Show History`[image: Access the local file History via VCS]
2. Then click the `Revert` button in Upper left Corner [image: Click to the Revert button.]

Hope this will help.