# Is it ok to use git reset --hard instead of git pull to deploy code on production?

Tags: git, deployment

I use git reset --hard origin/master to pull the commits from bitbucket. I did this to avoid any kind of merge conflict since I am using a single branch and I want the code on production exactly similar as I committed. I don't expect nor do I want any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Git might not always be ideal as a release management tool (it remains a versioning control tool).
Plus, that makes one additional tool to install on a production environment, which is not directly needed to run the program.

For instance, a reset --hard would not cleanup private non-versioned file, that might need to be removed: see "[How do I clear my local working directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/675797/6309)".

Depending on the nature of what you are deploying, a `git clean -d -x -f` might be needed in addition of the reset.

Comment: I am using git as a versioning tool as well. It's very handy to control your code and detect bug sources. I am very cautious about my local repository and always keep it so that I don't have to worry about removing files on production.