# git checkout doesn't remove the newly added files

Tags: git, version-control, version

I want to revert my repo to **exact state** of a previous commit. Then make a new commit  (as part of the reversion) and push to remote. I don't want to use `git push -f` so I don't want to rewrite the commits. I want to use one new commit and undo multiple changes.

so I ran `git checkout [HASH] -- .`

But I realized that this command doesn't exactly do the reversion. A file added in the later commits doesn't actually get removed.

How exactly do I revert in git?

Answer (score 1):

If your local git is recent enough (2.27+), `git restore` is the command to use :

```
git restore [HASH]
```

---

If for some reason, you cannot upgrade your local git to a recent enough version,
use `git read-tree` :

```
git read-tree [HASH]
```

Comment: To get the effect of `git restore <hash>` in old Git, use `git read-tree -u <hash>`.

Answer (score 0):

It works in the same as `git reset --hard`, but with the **important** difference, that `git checkout` is *working-directory* **safe**, so it doesn't *overwrite* existing changes in your *working directory*.

If you wish to *undo/revert* a commit you can do the following, using the `commit hash` from the commit where you will revert:

```
git revert <commit hash>
```

But you can also clear your [working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673407/how-do-i-clear-my-local-working-directory-in-git) and then you can do `git checkout <commit hash>`