# The svn repository I've imported into git using git-svn has moved

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I'm working with a git repository using git-svn. Everything went fine until the day the maintainers of the svn repository decided to move the repository to a different URL.

How can I tell my git-svn client to fetch from the new svn repository?

I've changes the svn URL in the `svn-remote` of `.git/config` but now I get the following error:

```
svn-remote.svn.url already set: https://old.svn.repo
wanted to set to: https://new.svn.repo
```

Comment: quite related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be trouble...since git-svn embeds the SVN url into each commit message. Hopefully that isn't a problem as well. You may need to rewrite your entire history to change all of the commit messages (using git filter-branch). But that could cause trouble if you've pushed anywhere else outside of back to SVN.

Comment: I probably have to rewrite the history. Since I want to reorganize other things as well I'll just make fresh svn clone.

Answer (score 1):

You might also need to change the `.git/svn/.metadata` file.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be enough. I'm still not able to fetch.