# How can I copy a git repository into a new svn repostory?

Tags: svn, git, initialization, repository, reverse

I have some code that I want to put into an svn repository for a client after doing some work on it in git, is there any way to initialize a svn repository using a git repository's history?

I have initialized git repositories from svn repositories, and regularly commit between existing svn and git repositories, but I don't know how to go about in the opposite direction, creating an svn repository from a git repository.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ImportingFromGit) has a good example.  An adapted example is described [here](http://justaddwater.dk/2009/07/08/importing-existing-git-repository-into-svn/).

The gist of it is that you need to fake out the first commit and then rebase and dcommit.

Answer (score 0):

try using [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) - Bidirectional operation between a Subversion repository and git...