# svn ci after a git push on github

Tags: svn, git, github

I have a project on `github` but I need to maintain a svn repo updated with every push.
I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn) question but I want to do it automatically.

Is there a way to tell github to do a `svn ci` when a push occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the svn interface on GitHub may work for you - you might want to check that out first. It is automatically kept up to date for your main branch.

`svn co http://svn.github.com/user/project`

However, if that is not sufficient, you can give GitHub a URL to ping when something is pushed, then setup a server to run a `git pull; svn ci` whenever it gets that ping.

Comment: Love this feature. Wish we could do `svn co http://svnhub.com/user/project` too `:P`