# How can I recover a Subversion repository from a git-svn copy?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am pretty sure I have tried everything, figured I would ask all the gurus on here.

Background:
I had an SVN repository on an old linux box.
I accessed this SVN repo with git-svn.
The system's hard drive crashed and the SVN repo was lost.

Question:

> Since I have an entire backup of the SVN repository on my local machine through me using GIT, I would like to figure out how to publish everything, including previous commits from my local machine to the new SVN server (that now is on a RAID 5 array).

Currently the projects still have the old SVN information in them, so I need to figure out how to get rid of that as well as migrating the GIT repo to the new SVN repo I set up.

I have contemplated setting up a remote GIT repo, but none of my co-programmers know/want to learn how to use GIT because currently they use the SVN plugin for eclipse and it is ultra easy, even though I am the one who saved everyone by using GIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [Git::SVNReplay](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Git-SVNReplay/) might fit the bill.

Comment: After i figured out how to install this, it seems to work!  Thank you so much!  have been looking for this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to push your Git repository up to a private repo at [GitHub](http://github.com), where you can use Git and everybody else can [use Subversion](http://github.com/blog/644-subversion-write-support) to access the same repository.

Comment: Would be nice, but too cheap when I have a working linux box in front of me =(  Have a few repos that we need to keep up with as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Pushing an existing git repository to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn) solves your problem.

Use

```
svn switch --relocate file:///tmp/repos file:///tmp/newlocation .
```

to connect existing checkouts to the new svn repository.

Comment: I have tried the steps in that link, since the repo was already tied to an SVN repo it makes it different.  I cannot make it past the "git svn fetch".