# Can I recover a subversion server from a local copy?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, recovery

My team has been using TortoiseSVN for version control. Recently the machine running our subversion server died, and we don't have a backup for it. I have an up-to-date copy of the repo on my local machine so we haven't lost any code, but we have lost all the history of the commits which is a big deal for us.

Is there any way to restore the server, or at least get access to the commit history, by using only 1 or more working copies of the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: the history is lost. Unlike Git, the SVN history is in the server only.

If some of the developers use git-svn, you can try recovering from it, see e.g. [How can I recover a Subversion repository from a git-svn copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3782112/6352677), https://superuser.com/q/318241/915977, or [possible to recreate svn repository from (full) git-svn clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13284762/6352677).

Maybe that's an opportunity for switching to Git!