# Trouble pushing from git to subversion using git-svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to push the existing git repo into svn.

There are solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn) and [here](http://draconianoverlord.com/2010/03/05/existing-git-into-svn.html).
That's what I'm doing:

1.Creating git repo:

```
$ mkdir /blabla/git_repo
$ cd /blabla/git_repo
$ git_init
$ touch hello.c
$ git add hello.c
$ git commit -m "init"
```

2.Creating svn repo:

```
$ svnadmin create /blabla/svn_repo
$ cd /blabla/svn_repo
$ vim conf/*
... making initial configuring ...
$ svnserve --daemon --root /blabla/svn_repo/
```

So, now I have pure svn repository and existing git repository.

3.Pushing git into svn

```
$ cd /blabla/git_repo
$ svn mkdir --parents svn://localhost/GIT/trunk -m "git import"
$ git svn init svn://localhost -T GIT/trunk
$ git svn fetch
Error from SVN, (220001): Item is not readable: Item is not readable
$ git branch -av
* master 54ab8bf init
```

So, the SVN branch is not apperaing!

If on step 3 I try to do this:

```
$ cd /blabla/git_repo
$ svn mkdir --parents svn://localhost/GIT/trunk -m "git import"
$ git svn init svn://localhost          <--  **no "-T" flag here**
$ git svn fetch
Authentication realm: <svn://localhost:3690> 1d926320-a80a-43d5-9e77-9dc2a43fc4f0
Password for 'arsen': 
W: +empty_dir: GIT/trunk
r1 = 8d3e31cf67f29846660ef20faf3454005101e012 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
$ git branch -av
* master          18cbfbd init
  remotes/git-svn 8d3e31c git-svn-id: svn://localhost@1 1d926320-a80a-43d5-9e77-9dc2a43fc4f0
```

then everything goes OK, except that I can't push git repository into GIT svn project, I can push it only into svn root.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the trouble.

Though there was "anon-access = read" string in svnserve.conf, I had to add manually "* = r" into svn authz file. Now it works, though doesn't makes sense for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put something in your SVN tree and try again.
(you may remove that later in svn by dump/load)

Comment: I've added and commited these files into SVN: /GIT/trunk/1, /GIT/2, /3. I removed and created git repository again. The same story.