# Using SVN to connect to a git repository

Tags: git, svn, uml, visual-paradigm

I'm using git for my source code management. For some reasons I have to to use VisualParadigm for my UML diagrams.

Unfortunately VisualParadigm only supports SVN. Is it possible to connect via SVN to a git repository or to the remote repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Push an existing git repository to a new SVN repository:
[Pushing an existing git repository to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn)
And your Visual Paradigm can that connect to the SVN repository.

Answer (score 6):

If the git repository is on `github`, you can do it directly—Github supports SVN access using the same URLs as one uses for git!

E.g.:

```
svn checkout https://github.com/offby1/rudybot.git/trunk rudybot
```

Checks the trunk (`master` in git) of rudybot out into a local SVN directory called `rudybot`.

[Branches etc are handled in the normal SVN manner, and are underneath `.../branches` from the top-level; if you just checkout the *...*`.git` URL, you'll get a directory containing both `trunk` and `branches`...]