# Push an existing git repository to an existing SVN repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have been asked for a school project to submit my work by pushing it to an **existing** SVN repository. It is an existing repository with some files already there. I have no need for these files or the previous commits.

I have been working on my assignment with a git repository on my. I would like to push my work to the SVN repository without losing any history. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain the history a little more? Have you used `git svn clone` to clone from SVN?

Comment: No not yet. I'm not sure if that is the correct way to approach this problem. So far I have done nothing to fix it. All the guides I see assume I have a bare/new SVN repo.

Comment: That is one way, and you are sure not to lose history. But more needs to be known: is your initial git import a copy of the SVN repo at some point? You said you worked on a local git repo, how did you get the files to work with?

Comment: My git repo is unrelated to my SVN repo. However at the end of the process I would like my SVN repo to be a copy of my git repo.

Comment: Ah, you didn't say you had to _create_ an SVN repository, it changes quite a few things...

Comment: I don't have to create an SVN repo, there is already one to submit to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pushing an existing git repository to SVN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do a mix. That is, first clone the svn with [git svn](http://gitmanual.org/git-svn.html). Then in this new repository, you [merge](http://gitmanual.org/git-merge.html) your work from your current git repository.

```
$ git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project/trunk
$ cd trunk
$ git checkout -b mywork
$ git pull /path/to/current/work/repository/.git master
```

Now you have your work in the `mywork` branch in the [clone](http://gitmanual.org/git-clone.html) from subversion. Time to merge and push.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge mywork
$ git svn dcommit
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I tried this but all of my git history were pushed as one svn commit, resulting commit history logs

Answer (score 0):

You can, as a pre-requisite ensure that all your changes in git have been applied or merged into the `master` branch.

Then you can run `git-svn rebase` to merge any updates from svn and finally `git-svn dcommit` to commit changes.

There is a detailed explanation here - cf - http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/