# git svn sync failure

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am following this thread
[Pushing an existing git repository to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn)
to sync a git repository to svn. However I am stuck at git svn fetch

```
git svn fetch
RA layer request failed: REPORT of '/svnrepos/my_git/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk size: Secure connection truncated (https://my.svn.net) at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 5061
```

Anybody has an idea of how to work around this...

[Additional information]: I am behind a corporate proxy, but the svn url is reachable without proxy. Anyway I already tried set and unset http-proxy-host and http-proxy-host, http-proxy-port, http-proxy-username, http-proxy-password, none of which worked.

[Additional information 2] I can use both "svn co" and "git svn clone" to checkout the svn url

Comment: Are you able to do a `svn checkout` of that path in the same machine?

Comment: @madth3 yes, I am able to. I am actually given exclusive svn r/w to that svn url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whoever running into the same problem, my solution is to pass in --no-minimum-url to git svn init before I did git svn fetch

```
git svn init <svn.url> -s --no-minimize-url
git svn fetch
```

Turns out since the svn server is not managed by us, some information in svn root is intentionally hidden from us. So if the git svn client tries to read that information from svn root, it would fail. --no-minimize-url will prevent git svn client from going there.

Comment: @Sheng: The parameter is called "--no-minimize-url" and not "--no--minimum-url". Could you update your answer?