# git-svn multiple git repositories to same svn repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have two separate git repositories - git1 and git2. Due to my advisor's recommendation, I need to copy them to the university's svn repository such that all git repo contributors can simultaneously update the university SVN repo along with the git repos.

git-svn looks like a good solution. I followed instructions in the top answer in [Pushing an existing git repository to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn) and was able to link one git repository. Is it possible to link both git repos as two folders in the same svn repo?

The folder structure might look like:

- SVN-repo

  - project1 #links git1 using git-svn

    - trunk
    - branches
    - tags
  - project2 #links git2 using git-svn

    - trunk
    - branches
    - tags

Can someone point how this can be achieved? Indicating some actual instructions might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone faces the same problem, I am indicating my solution here.

I was able to achieve this by creating two projects in the SVN repo with standard structure(trunk, branches and tags) and then using git-svn to link each git repo to a SVN project. The exact set of instructions can be seen from my blog post: http://lookupnotes.blogspot.com/2013/01/git-to-svn.html