# How can i push a git history to svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have an existing git repository with a long history. For business reasons i have to mirror that repository to a svn server. I tried several ways but always failed so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hard time do it some time ago, so I've collected some steps from different sources to do it.This procedure will keep your full git history.
Before starting make sure to have a backup copy of your repository.

The first thing to do is create an empty `svn` repository. When you're done with it be sure to have `git-svn` installed and edit yout `.git/config` to track your newly created `svn` repos:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = https://your.svn.repo
fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

Now you can fetch your `svn` repo:

```
git svn fetch
```

You should see the remote branch following your `svn` repo, you can check with:

```
git branch -a
```

Now get the hash of your `root commit` and of the `svn` branch:

```
git rev-list --parents master | grep '^.\{40\}$'
git rev-parse remotes/git-svn
```

Create the graft:

```
echo <hash-of-root-commit> <hash-of-svn-branch-commit> >> .git/info/grafts
```

Now if you use a graphical wrapper for `git` (I use `tig`) you should see that your `root commit` descends from the `svn-branch`.

At this point you have to propagate the `graft` making it permanent:

```
git filter-branch -- remotes/git-svn --all
```

Now we don't need it anymore so we can delete it

```
rm .git/info/grafts
```

Check with your graphical git wrapper that the `svn-branch` is the `master` ancestor.

Now you're almost done, rebase your history on top of trunk:

```
git svn rebase
```

Now your ready to commit to your `svn` repo using

```
git svn dcommit
```

I've created this procedure merging infos I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn/) and [here](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/10/26/3815034), so thanks to the respective authors. I've modified the first part because the proposed procedure didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `git-svn` approach leads to partial history loss. Consider using [SubGit](http://subgit.com) instead, it's able to convert Git repository into SVN keeping the history of all branches.

Below you can find an example of using SubGit in a local mode, i.e. when both Subversion and Git repositories reside on the same host:

```
$ subgit configure SVN_REPO
# adjust SVN_REPO/conf/subgit.conf, so git.default.repository points to GIT_REPO
# adjust SVN_REPO/conf/authors.txt to map SVN usernames to Git identities
$ subgit install SVN_REPO
$ subgit uninstall --purge SVN_REPO
```

Once we've converted Linux kernel Git repository to SVN this way. Hope that helps.