# How to push local git repository to svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have following setup:

1) Network drive location is the bare git repo (lets say it is "X:\Projects\MyProject")

2) My local location where my development is happening is C:\Projects\MyProject

3) My svn repo that doesn't follow standard layout of branches, tags, etc (not my decision) is at http://mysite:8081/svn/MyProject

My question is how do I push MyProject from 1 or 2 to SVN repo keeping all the history stored at 1?

I tried steps advised in [Pushing an existing git repository to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn) but on the step I am getting to git svn rebase I am getting error "Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After more digging into this I was finally able to figure out that the issue was caused by svn repo didn't had any commits. So just by initializing trunk, branches in svn and then init git svn into C:\Projects\MyProject all other steps in that linked question worked fine