# commit a local git repo to svn

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have a local git repo with my current Project. Now I want to commit with the git svn tool, the git repo to a SVN repo.

I've read this post: [pushing an existing git reposotory to svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn) but somehow it's not working in my case.

What I've tried:

```
/Documents/Workspace (master)
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Because I'm on Windows I've createt a new Folder inside the svn repo, and checked it out to

```
/documents/Workspace

/Documents/Workspace (master)
$ ls
.git
Current-Project/
.svn
```

till now the git repo, and the svn repo are in the same folder.

I think, from the post above, step 1 and 2 are done so far

> 1. cd /path/to/git/localrepo
> 2. svn mkdir --parents protocol:///path/to/repo/PROJECT/trunk -m "Importing git repo"
> 3. git svn init protocol:///path/to/repo/PROJECT -s
> 4. git svn fetch
> 5. git rebase origin/trunk
>      5.1.  git status
>      5.2.  git add (conflicted-files)
>      5.3.  git rebase --continue
>      5.4.  (repeat 5.1.)
> 6. git svn dcommit

Step 3,4,5 are done (in Step 4 there are nothig to fetch because it's an empty folder)

but the git svn dcommit gives me following error:

```
/Documents/Workspace (master)
$ git svn dcommit
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty. at C:/Users/benjaminulrich/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 913.
```

Can't see why it's not working, can anyone help?

Comment: Did you actually run the `git svn fetch`? Even if the svn repo is _empty_ git still needs to create the revisions created on it so that you can do the rebase on top of the (fetched) trunk used on step 5.

Comment: yes i runed the command

Comment: and so I assume that when you are going to run the `git svn dcommit`, you are working on a branch that starts from an svn revision, right? If that is indeed the case (make sure by using git log, for example), I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?