# Copy SVN repository into subfolder of another server's repository, with history

Tags: svn, svnadmin

SVN repo 1: `https://local.server.001/svn/repo1`

SVN repo 2: `https://local.server.002/svn/repo2`

We want to move repo1 (from server 001) into a **subfolder** of repo2, called (for example) 'repo1'.

This is to say, repo1 will be copied into this location:

`https://local.server.002/svn/repo2/trunk/repo1`

Doing this with simple file copies is simple. What I'm trying to do, however, is to achieve this while *preserving the history of the files being copied into the repo1 folder of the repo2 repository*.

I have found plenty of examples of copying between *repositories* - or between repositories on different servers - but I'm having trouble finding examples of this specific type of situation.

Please help! Thanks.

We're all TortoiseSVN users, so any answer which uses the TorsoiseSVN GUI would be a plus. Our SVN servers run on VisualSVN.

EDIT - Adding beautiful illustration:

[image: SVN repo into another repo's folder]

EDIT 2 - Still can't get it to work:

Ran this on repo 1: `sysadmin dump C:\Repositories\repo1 > D:\dump\repo1`

This worked. Copied the `repo1` dump file onto server 2. I then ran:

`svnadmin load --parent-dir repo1 C:\Repositories\repo2 < D:\someDir\repo1`

I'm blocked on this error:

`Started new transaction, based on original revision 1. adding path : repo1/trunk ...svnadmin: E160013: File not found: transaction '281-96', path '/repo1/trunk'`

I tried committing a top-level folder `repo1` into the `repo2` repository, but no luck.

Comment: Say repo1 and repo2 both have a revisionX. You can't have two separate revisionX's in one repo, so I don't think this can be done. Perhaps you could add repo1 as an [external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals).

Comment: From (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479361/can-i-move-an-existing-subversion-repository-into-a-new-parent-repository-and-r) I found this suggestion:

`svnadmin dump http://oldrepo/ > mydump`
`svnadmin load --parent-dir my/new/folder http://newrepo/ < mydump`

..with `--parent-dir` being the key. I'm tempted to try it. I wonder how this gets around the revision number conflict that you bring up?

(For reference: our repo1 is at rev 24050. repo2 is much newer, say at rev 3000.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to migrate svn to another repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939963/how-to-migrate-svn-to-another-repository)

Comment: Hmm, I guess it can be done, see the [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate).

Comment: Your question is answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795887/how-to-copy-svn-repository-as-a-folder-to-another-repository-with-history

Comment: See edits. Cannot get this to work. Been trying for hours and hours.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Certainly not a duplicate of that issue. It doesn't even mention loading into a subfolder... it speaks only of a simple repo-to-repo dump/load.

Comment: @MatthewHousser - RLLY? Did you try to read question and answer?

Comment: The question is covered in SVNBook and has been answered many times on StackOverflow, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11598608/761095

Comment: Did you create the `repo1` directory inside `repo2` before running `svnadmin load`? e.g. `svn mkdir file:///C:/Repositories/repo2/repo1` Note that you must create the directory using `svn mkdir` in order to add it to the repo. See the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) for details.

Comment: I created `repo1` dir in `repo2` repo by committing the folder via TortoiseSVN. Should this not have been enough?

Comment: I'm following everyone's steps *exactly*, and I still cannot get past the error message. :(

Comment: @Biswajit_86 - yes, appears that it's answered there (I think), but yet I am blocked on the error message that I have updated in my original question. I've followed the steps exactly as stated, including adding the new /repo1 top-level directory in the repo2 repository. I did this using TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha. It seems that the difference between my case and the other similar cases on S/O is that *my repositories use the default /branch /tags /trunk structure*.

The eventual sequence for me was:

`svnadmin dump C:/Repositories/repo1 > D:/dump/repo1.dump`

`svndumpfilter include /trunk < D:/dump/repo1.dump > D:/dump/repo1.filtered.dump`

I then created (via TortoiseSVN) a top-level `repo1` folder inside the `repo2` repository.

This next line **failed** for me, despite it following all the suggested examples:

`svnadmin load --parent-dir /repo1 C:/Repositories/repo2 < D:/dump/repo1.filtered.dump`

No good. Didn't work. Error of the type `Started new transaction, based on original revision 1. adding path : repo1/trunk ...svnadmin: E160013: File not found: transaction '281-96', path '/repo1/trunk'` kept being returned. This is where I got stuck. I even created the `repo1` folder, so why this message!!

..Well, it's because of the branches/tags/trunk folder structure that is VisualSVN's default. Once I changed the `load` statement to include `/trunk` before the `repo1` folder, it all worked:

`svnadmin load --parent-dir /trunk/repo1 C:/Repositories/repo2 < D:/dump/repo1.filtered.dump`

It was looking for a `/repo1` folder at the *highest* level, that is to say, living next to `tags`, `branches` and `trunk`.

(After this, I had to do an SVN move to move everything from /trunk/repo1/trunk/* to /trunk/repo1. Seems the dump/load re-created the 'trunk' folder, which I didn't want.